# Firebase Simple Login $logout function does not set user property to null

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

Per the documentation on the $logout method for $firebaseSimpleLogin, the API says clearly that

> When logout is called, the $firebaseSimpleLogin:logout event will be fired, and the user >property on the object will be set to null.

However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
  var firebaseUrl = 'https://MYURL.firebaseio.com/';
  var firebaseObject = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);

  $rootScope.firebaseLoginObject = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseObject, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else if (user) {
      console.log('User ID: ' + user.uid + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);
    } else {
      console.log('User is logged out');
      // user is logged out
    }
  });

  // Function for logging out.
  $scope.logout = function() {
    $rootScope.firebaseLoginObject.$logout();
    console.log('i logged out successfully');
    console.log($rootScope.firebaseLoginObject);
    console.log($rootScope.firebaseLoginObject.user);
    console.log($rootScope.user);
    $location.path('/');
  };
```

The output I get in the console after clicking "ng-click=logout()" shows that $rootScope.firebaseLoginObject is not set to null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with $scope.logout. Your console.log statements are being executed before the $logout function has completed its work.

```
  $scope.logout = function() {
    $rootScope.firebaseLoginObject.$logout();

    // This is not necessarily true. At this point, you may still be
    // logged in since $logout can take an unknown amount of time to finish.

    console.log('i logged out successfully');
    console.log($rootScope.firebaseLoginObject);
    console.log($rootScope.firebaseLoginObject.user);
    console.log($rootScope.user);
    $location.path('/');
  };
```

To ensure you're logging the state of the firebaseLoginObject after $logout has finished, wait until the logout event has been broadcasted on $rootScope.

```
  $rootScope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout", function(event) {
    // Log values here.
  });
```